# What is the Superpartner of a glass?

Tags: particle-physics, supersymmetry, spin-models

A little context: This summer I visited Switzerland and had the chance to tour CERN. While there, I saw through an open door this question written at the top of a chalkboard in [John Ellis's office](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsXo7C7KgDk).

I cannot make heads or tails of this question: "What is the Superpartner of a glass?" I have a decent understanding of glasses from a condensed matter standpoint (for example, [Spin Glasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_glass)), but an admittedly shallow understanding of [Supersymmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry) and [Superpartners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpartner).

It seems to me that the question is asking about what sort of material one might make if all of the particles of a glass were swapped for their respective Superpartners but the geometry and bond associations were left unchanged. However, I am not sure if that is the question, and frankly, I am not even sure if that question makes any sense (e.g. Why should we expect the Superpartners to bond with one another at all?). Perhaps there is a subtlety to Supersymmetric theory that I am unaware of which might treat a large quantum mechanical system as a quasi-particle that mathematically should have its own Superpartner. I just don't know.

If someone can address the question itself (i.e. What is the Superpartner of a glass?), that would be great, but what I am really interested in is why this question is interesting. I am hoping that someone can explain what makes this a good research question or pet project. What is the question actually addressing, and what is the implied relationship between Supersymmetry and glasses?

In short, why would anyone think to ask this question?

**EDIT:** Based on the comments, I am adding a link to a couple of papers on the supersymmetry of spin glass. They are pretty far beyond what I understand, but perhaps someone with more knowledge then me will find them useful when thinking about this question.

http://perso.crans.org/lecomtev/articles/kurchan_susy_JDP1_1992.pdf

http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0701627

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. "Superpartners" is something *elementary fields* in a supersymmetric QFT have. What do you mean by "superpartner of a glass", that's just not a well-defined question - a glass is not a quantum field which has a superpartner, it's a complex condensed matter system.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I know. Unfortunately, you and I appear to have precisely the same question. This is what I ask at the bottom of the post.

Comment: ...it might be a joke. It might be a vague research question someone is pursuing. We can't look into the mind of the person who wrote that line on a random blackboard. Unless you can find some actual reference talking about this, this is a completely ill-defined question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Fair enough. I was (and still am) hoping that perhaps there is something subtle about this question that I am missing. There is [this paper](http://perso.crans.org/lecomtev/articles/kurchan_susy_JDP1_1992.pdf) and [this one](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0701627) which discuss how spin glasses display supersymmetry by being invariant under certain operations and can be analyzed accordingly, but honestly, they are pretty far above my pay-grade and I really don't understand why displaying a supersymmetry would imply having a superpartner.

Comment: A nice Bordeaux, I would say. Chateau Margaux 1990 anyone? Physicists, even at CERN, are occasionally known to have a sense of humor. And to like good wine.

Comment: The following is a comment that user Chapette tried to edit into the post: "*A little more context on the original question. This was written on John Ellis' blackboard, which makes all the difference since is a well-known place for good-humoured jokes at CERN. Also, it was written in the presence of the undersigned by a friend. She meant "glass" as in "the one I use to drink my water right now", the meaning being "what would a macroscopic object made out of superpartners be like?". A playful yet rather valid philosophical question.*"